# Passing datatypes of the same definition but in different namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

Here is my quandary. I have written a tool that utilized PNG++ for converting graphics. Aside from the PNG output, I also used several data types in its library which work as generic types separate from anything PNG specific.

I am now moving that core functionality into shared object, and I don't want this library to be dependent on PNG++ just for a couple data types. I can copy these types into my library since the code is FOSS, but I would want to bring them into my project's namespace. All of which leads me to my question.

If I copy these types just as they are into my library, into another namespace, will they be directly compatible with PNG++ still? My gut feeling on this is 'no,' and if that is the case, should I just stop worrying and make PNG++ a dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what the types are, if they are just typedefs then the types will be convertible.

If they are structures/classes then the types in each namespace will be unrelated and not automatically convertible.

Comment: That's basically what I expected. Thanks for the confirmation.